# React-native -> no variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile

I hope you are doing well

I'm presently engaged in a React Native project and encountering an issue specific to Android. The project performs well with **React Native version** `0.64.3` (an older version). However, considering the project requirements, **I aim to upgrade the React Native version to** `7.1.8`, Upon attempting to sync the project with Gradle files, I encountered this problem

[image]

Despite conducting a thorough search for similar issues, I haven't found any relevant solutions. I've ensured that all necessary SDKs are installed, including the gradle SDK, zulu11. Additionally, pertinent details about my project include:

**->** Android Gradle Plugin version 7.3.1

**->** Gradle version 7.6.1.

**->** React-native version 0.71.8

thank you for your timect